# What is a PR in Angular parlance?

Tags: angularjs

I often see the term *PR* appear in Angular circles, for example on this [contribution checklist](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Contribution-Checklist). Its definition is Google resistant, however, since it's an overloaded acronym.

From an Angular perspective, what does PR mean?

Comment: +1 for an honest and refreshing question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not really Angular parlance, but github parlance:

PR stands for [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests)